# Removing spaces between entries in a compressed bibliography

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to write a very compressed bibliography. I almost have a solution, but annoying spacing issues keep cropping up.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%             
  \section*{\refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{{\bf #1}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Cite two papers\cite{MaynardSmith1995,Adami2000b}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mwe_bib}{}

\end{document}
```

Where mwe_bib.bib is

```
@Article{Adami2000b,
 author =       {C. Adami},
 journal =      {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA}, 
 year =         {2000},
 volume =       {97},
 pages =        {4463-4468}
}

@Book{MaynardSmith1995,
 author =    {J. {Maynard Smith} and E. Szathm\'{a}ry},
 title =     {The Major Evolutionary Transitions},
 publisher = {Oxford University Press},
 year =      {1995},
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

What I want to do is remove the large space between the end of reference 1 and the beginning of reference 2. That is, between "1995." and "2."

I've searched for a solution for hours, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to Thomas and Mico, the above MWE now works. Unfortunately, by adding just one more reference, the problem pops back up. Here's a new MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%             
  \section*{\refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{{\bf #1}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Cite three papers\cite{MaynardSmith1995,Adami2000b,Adami2002}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mwe_bib}{}

\end{document}
```

where unsrt has been modified according to Mico's comment, using \hspace{0pt} and mwe_bib.bib is now

```
@Article{Adami2000b,
  author =       {C. Adami},
  journal =      {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA}, 
  year =         {2000},
  volume =       {97},
  pages =        {4463-4468}
}

@Book{MaynardSmith1995,
  author =   {J. {Maynard Smith} and E. Szathm\'{a}ry},
  title =    {The Major Evolutionary Transitions},
  publisher =    {Oxford University Press},
  year =     {1995},
}

@Article{Adami2002,
  author =       {C. Adami},
  journal =      {BioEssays},
  year =         {2002},
  volume =       {24},
  pages =        {1085-1094}
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Now we have an ugly space between the end of the 2nd reference and the beginning of the 3rd. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the changes above, the solution required line 8 below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%             
  \section*{\refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{{\bf \olditem}}
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}

Cite three papers\cite{MaynardSmith1995,Adami2000b,Adami2002}.

\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{unsrt}{}

\end{document}
```

Now the output looks as it should:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The idea I propose is to add breakable spaces.

Put the file 'unsrt.bst' in your working directory and modify line 393 (in my latex version) ; the code looks like this :

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":" * pages n.dashify * } % !!!!!!!!!! here
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Modify ":" by " : ". This solution is not very clean, but it may be a start.

Comment: +1. Instead of a space, though, consider `\hspace{0pt}`. That way, a line break is still permitted, but no space will show up in case no line break is generated.

Comment: Thanks Thomas and Mico. You fixed the problem for the MWE. However, in my larger document, the problem persists. I'll edit the question with a new MWE to highlight the problem.